# how to information about duplicate items

Tags: count, duplicates, singlestore

I have a table with IP and serial number

I want to seee which duplicate IP and also (in another command ) duplicate Serial number .

so when I will run the command I will see :

this resualt to get duplicate IP

```
Serial number IP 
123           1.1.1.1
333           1.1.1.1
222           2.2.2.2
999           2.2.2.2
```

This resualt to get duplicate serial number:

```
Serial number IP 
123           1.1.1.1
123           9.8.7.5
222           33.33.2.1
222           2.2.2.2
```

I have try this

```
   SELECT IP, COUNT(SN) 
FROM   sample.table1
GROUP BY SN
HAVING COUNT(IP) > 1
```

but the answer is all that is duplicated , and show me just the IP 
so when I have duplicated SN I see only the first IP of it ..

Thanks ,

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a window function.  Let me see if I can cook up some sql

```
select IP, SN from (
    select IP, SN, count(*) over (partition by SN) as c  
    from sample.table1) sub
where c > 1
```

and you can replace SN with IP to get the other one.